# Bold and flat text in one run with XWPFRun, writing into word

Tags: java, text, ms-word, apache-poi, xwpf

Is it possible to set bold to true and false in one run?

I have the following code on the moment :

```
XWPFParagraph paragraph = nieuwDocument.createParagraph();

XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
run.setBold(true);


for (XWPFParagraph paragraphs: paragraphList)
{   

    if(paragraphs.getStyle() !=null)
    {   
      if(paragraphs.getStyle().equals(kop) || paragraphs.getStyle().equals(tussenkop))
      { 
        run.addBreak();
        run.setText(paragraphs.getText());
        run.addCarriageReturn();
      }  
        if(paragraphs.getNumFmt() != null)
      { 
        //run.setBold(false)
        run.addTab();
        run.setText(paragraphs.getText());
        run.addCarriageReturn();
 }    
}
```

I have tried to add `run.setBold(false)` into `if(paragraphs.getNumFmt() != null)` statement but then all the text is flat again.

I would like the text from the last `if` statement flat and from the first `if` bold.

**Update** (with 2 different runs)

If I create two runs my text order is going wrong.

```
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
run.setBold(true);

XWPFRun runTwo = paragraph.createRun();
runTwo.setBold(false);

for (XWPFParagraph paragraphs: paragraphList)
  { 

    if(paragraphs.getStyle() !=null)
    {   
     if(paragraphs.getStyle().equals(kop) || paragraphs.getStyle().equals(tussenkop))
         {  
           run.addBreak();
           run.setText(paragraphs.getText());
           run.addCarriageReturn();
          }  

          if(paragraphs.getNumFmt() != null)
          {     
            runTwo.addTab();
            runTwo.setText(paragraphs.getText());
            runTwo.addCarriageReturn();
          }
```

[Right order (with first code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mibNz.jpg)

[Wrong order (second code with two runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc598.jpg)

Hope this make it clearer

Comment: "Is it possible to set bold to true and false in one run?": No.

Comment: @Alex Richter, Do u have any solution to that?  I can make two `XWPFRun` but then the text is going out of the right order.

Comment: Why "the text is going out of the right order" using multiple runs? All other people are using multiple runs for styling text without any problems. Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows your problem in reproducible manner.

Comment: @AxelRichter Alright I have tried to, see my update

Comment: @AxelRichter If u have some free time I would appreciate it if u can have a look at my updated post.

Comment: You haven't read the linked help page of how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Using the code you provides, helpers cannot create their own test cases in an easy way. And I will not bothering myself with creating test cases based on suspicions which then possibly are wrong. This is wasted time.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you. Its a little bit hard coded you should get the point!

```
public static void textStyledInbetween(XWPFDocument document, String text1, String style1, String text2, String style2, String text3, String style3) {
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
 
    XWPFRun run1 = paragraph.createRun();
    XWPFRun run2 = paragraph.createRun();
    XWPFRun run3 = paragraph.createRun();
    paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH);
    run1.setFontSize(12);
    run1.setFontFamily("Arial");
    run2.setFontSize(12);
    run2.setFontFamily("Arial");
    run3.setFontSize(12);
    run3.setFontFamily("Arial");

    if (text1 != null) {
        if (style1 != null) {
            if (style1.equals("Bold")) {
                run1.setBold(true);
            } else if (style1.equals("Italian")) {
                run1.setItalic(true);
            }
        }
        run1.setText(text1);
        run1.setBold(false);
        run1.setItalic(false);
    }

    if (text2 != null) {
        if (style2 != null) {
            if (style2.equals("Bold")) {
                run2.setBold(true);
            } else if (style2.equals("Italian")) {
                run2.setItalic(true);
            }
        }
        run2.setText(text2);
    }

    if (text3 != null) {
        if (style3 != null) {
            if (style3.equals("Bold")) {
                run3.setBold(true);
            } else if (style3.equals("Italian")) {
                run3.setItalic(true);
            }
        }
        run3.setText(text3);
    }
}
```